# Will datetime datatype in a table column update the current time automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Will datetime datatype in a table column(last_modified_timestamp) update the current time automatically?

i have a table column as shown below , i need to know whether it will insert the current time in the column automatically?

How i know currently i have default settings in my table?

i changed it to insert ...not for updating !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not. How would you expect SQL to guess which datetime columns should be automatically updated like this, and yet others are meant to record, e.g. historic dates.

For INSERT purposes, you can have a DEFAULT constraint on the column that inserts the current date (Getdate()/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

But for UPDATEs to work, you'd have to implement a trigger.

---

For INSERT purposes, and using the table designer, you can look at the "Default Value or Binding" property - you'd set this to `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` or `(GetDate())` (they mean the same thing). Or in the Object Explorer, you can look at the constraints on the table - if there's a default set, it will appear in there.

---

Also, worth pointing out that a default is exactly as it sounds - there's nothing to prevent someone providing their own value for this column. If you want to prevent this, then trigger's are probably the answer (although a lot of people dislike triggers).

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it wont.

You either need to specify a [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        LastDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID) SELECT 1

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```

Or make use of [triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), or update the values manually using [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) in your `INSERT/UPDATES`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely NOT.

You can use DEFAULT to be `getdate()` which will add your current datetime for your column

If default is set on a column, you can see that in your table constraints. Check in the table properties, or type `sp_help <tablename>`

Comment: @user106528 - Edited my answer to give details on where you can find default value set on column

Answer (score 0):

If you use the use DEFAULT getdate() you must disable the nulls for that column, and if you sent a null then sql will set the default.

Comment: DEFAULT on column cosion_structure_code
DEFAULT on column incoete_flag
DEFAULT on column pur_flag
DEFAULT on column use_client_default_f_flag
DEFAULT on column opel_code
FOREIGN KEY
 
FOREIGN KEY
 
PRIMARY KEY (clustered)

Comment: These are my constraints in this there is no last_modified_timestamp coloumn

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you might need a trigger to update the date when an update is made.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      David Forck
-- Create date: 12Nov10
-- Description: Update last modified date
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdateLastModified
   ON  dbo.table1
   AFTER update
AS 
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

update dbo.table1
set last_modified_timestap=getdate()
where ID in (select ID from inserted)



END
GO
```